# Java: Name ambiguity between outer and inner class methods

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes, ambiguity, outer-classes

Suppose I have:

```
public class OuterClass() {

  public class InnerClass {
    public void someMethod(int x) {
      someMethod(x);
    }
  }

  public void someMethod(int x) {
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

How do I resolve the ambiguity between the `someMethod()` of the outer class and the `someMethod()` of the inner class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can refer to the outer with `OuterClass.this`, or call the method with `OuterClass.this.method()`.

However, as a point of design, sharing the name is confusing, to say the least. It might be reasonable if the inner class represented an extension or, say, a concrete implementation of an abstract method, but that would be clearer by calling super.method. Calling a super method directly, (as it looks like you're intending to do?), is confusing.

Answer (score 6):

Scope it to the outer class with `OuterClass.this.someMethod()`:

```
public class OuterClass {

  public class InnerClass {

    public void someMethod(int x) {
      OuterClass.this.someMethod(x);
    }
  }

  public void someMethod(int x) {
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Aw... Steve B. posted the same answer just before me. I will leave mine here for the example code.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming ambiguity is a good practice. Especially if you apply it in the upward and backward architecture.